# How to express classes on the axis of a heatmap in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I created a very simple heatmap chart with Seaborn displaying a similarity square matrix. Here is the one line of code I used:

```
sns.heatmap(sim_mat, linewidths=0, square=True, robust=True)
sns.plt.show()
```

and this is the output I get:

[image]

What I'd like to do is to represent on the x and y axis not the labels of my instances but a colored indicator (imagine something like a small palplot on each axis) where each color represents another variable associated to each instance (let's say I have this info stored a list named `labels`) plus another legend for this kind of information next to the one specifying the colors of the heatmap (one like that for the `lmplot`). It is important that the two informations have different color palettes.

Is this possible in Seaborn?

**UPDATE**

What I am looking for is a `clustermap` as correctly suggested.

```
sns.clustermap(sim_mat, row_colors=label_cols, col_colors=label_cols
    row_cluster=False, col_cluster=False)
```

Here is what I am getting btw, the dots and lines are too small and I do not see  a way to enlarge them in the documentation. I'd like to

Plus, how can I add a legend and put the two one next to the other in the same position?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use `clusterplot` with side colors and the clustering turned off. See this example http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/structured_heatmap.html.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two options:

First, `heatmap` is an Axes level figure, so you could set up a main large main heatmap axes for the correlation matrix and flank it with heatmaps that you then pass class colors to yourself. This will be a little bit of work, but gives you lots of control over how everything works.

This is more or less an option in `clustermap` though, so I'm going to demonstrate how to do it that way here. It's a bit of a hack, but it will work.

First, we'll load the sample data and do a bit of roundabout transformations to get colors for the class labels.

```
networks = sns.load_dataset("brain_networks", index_col=0, header=[0, 1, 2])
network_labels = networks.columns.get_level_values("network")
network_pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(network_labels.unique().size,
                                    light=.9, dark=.1, reverse=True,
                                    start=1, rot=-2)
network_lut = dict(zip(map(str, network_labels.unique()), network_pal))

network_colors = pd.Series(network_labels).map(network_lut)
```

Next we call `clustermap` to make the main plot.

```
g = sns.clustermap(networks.corr(),

                  # Turn off the clustering
                  row_cluster=False, col_cluster=False,

                  # Add colored class labels
                  row_colors=network_colors, col_colors=network_colors,

                  # Make the plot look better when many rows/cols
                  linewidths=0, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)
```

The side colors are drawn with a heatmap, which matplotlib thinks of as quantitative data and thus there's not a straightforward way to get a legend directly from it. Instead of that, we'll add an invisible barplot with the right colors and labels, then add a legend for *that*.

```
for label in network_labels.unique():
    g.ax_col_dendrogram.bar(0, 0, color=network_lut[label],
                            label=label, linewidth=0)
g.ax_col_dendrogram.legend(loc="center", ncol=6)
```

Finally, let's move the colorbar to take up the empty space where the row dendrogram would normally be and save the figure.

```
g.cax.set_position([.15, .2, .03, .45])
g.savefig("clustermap.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Building on the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27992943/7311767), I think it's worth noting the possibility of multiple colour levels for labels - as noted in the clustermap docs ({row,col}_colors). I couldn't find an example of multiple levels, so I thought I'd share an example here.

```
networks = sns.load_dataset("brain_networks", index_col=0, header=[0, 1, 2])
```

### network level

```
network_labels = networks.columns.get_level_values("network")
network_pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(network_labels.unique().size, light=.9, dark=.1, reverse=True, start=1, rot=-2)
network_lut = dict(zip(map(str, network_labels.unique()), network_pal))
```

#### Create index using the columns for networks

```
network_colors = pd.Series(network_labels, index=networks.columns).map(network_lut)
```

### node level

```
node_labels = networks.columns.get_level_values("node")
node_pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(node_labels.unique().size)
node_lut = dict(zip(map(str, node_labels.unique()), node_pal))
```

#### Create index using the columns for nodes

```
node_colors = pd.Series(node_labels, index=networks.columns).map(node_lut)
```

#### Create dataframe for row and column color levels

```
network_node_colors = pd.DataFrame(network_colors).join(pd.DataFrame(node_colors))
```

### create `clustermap`

```
g = sns.clustermap(networks.corr(),
# Turn off the clustering
row_cluster=False, col_cluster=False,
# Add colored class labels using data frame created from node and network colors
row_colors = network_node_colors,
col_colors = network_node_colors,
# Make the plot look better when many rows/cols
linewidths=0,
xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False,
center=0, cmap="vlag")
```

### create two legends - one for each level by creating invisible column and row barplots (as per above)

#### network legend

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import gcf

for label in network_labels.unique():
    g.ax_col_dendrogram.bar(0, 0, color=network_lut[label], label=label, linewidth=0)

l1 = g.ax_col_dendrogram.legend(title='Network', loc="center", ncol=5, bbox_to_anchor=(0.47, 0.8), bbox_transform=gcf().transFigure)
```

#### node legend

```
for label in node_labels.unique():
    g.ax_row_dendrogram.bar(0, 0, color=node_lut[label], label=label, linewidth=0)

l2 = g.ax_row_dendrogram.legend(title='Node', loc="center", ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(0.8, 0.8), bbox_transform=gcf().transFigure)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for today. This is one of the most useful answers I've ever come across; I never would have figured this out by myself. Thank you!!

Comment: Something like this should be integrated into sns.clustermap.

Answer (score 0):

When both dendrograms are used one can also add a new hidden axis and draw the legend.

```
ax= f.add_axes((0,0,0,0))
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

for label in node_labels.unique():
    ax.bar(0, 0, color=node_lut[label], label=label, linewidth=0)

l2 = g.ax_row_dendrogram.legend(title='Node', loc="center", ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(0.8, 0.8), bbox_transform=f.transFigure)
```