# How to create a heatmap with colsidebar like R in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap, seaborn

I want to plot a heatmap with something like status bar.

What I want to plot is exactly [here](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/r/heatmap/).

[heatmap with status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlJIf.png)

Above heatmap, there is the bar(red and blue).

I found this bar can be created with ColSideColors in R.

But I cannot find the way to do this in Python.

If anyone knows the way, please tell me...!

Comment: So what are you after? The heatmap or the status bar? would be good if you have codes of what you have done though.

Comment: Pretty sure that is called a dendogram.  `scipy` and I think `seaborn` have code for plotting them

Comment: > Tuan333


thanks to comment !
now, i write a code like bellow.


```python
data = random((10, 10))

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data)

ax.set_xticks(arange(data.shape[0]) + 0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(arange(data.shape[1]) + 0.5, minor=False)

ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()

pyplot.show()
```

Comment: > tacaswell thanks to comment ! now, I use matplotlib.pcolor() or seaborn.heatmap() but I cannot find the way to plot the bar (under the dendrogram) and heatmap together...

Comment: I found the article which seems to be related in this task.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988846/how-to-express-classes-on-the-axis-of-a-heatmap-in-seaborn

Thanks to advices !