# Seaborn clustermap row color with legend

Tags: python-2.7, seaborn

I found the following solution to add a row color legend to a Seaborn clustermap:

[How to express classes on the axis of a heatmap in Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988846/how-to-express-classes-on-the-axis-of-a-heatmap-in-seaborn)

I have two related questions:

1. how to move the legend to the bottom of the clustermap?
2. if the index of the dataframe representing row_color has a a name, it appears as a label under the colored row. How to increase the fontsize of that label?

Answer (score 5):

In order to add color legend, first, you need to create legend_TN .

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import seaborn as sns
legend_TN = [mpatches.Patch(color=c, label=l) for c,l in df[['tissue type','label']].drop_duplicates().values]
```

then `g=sns.clustermap(...)`

```
l2=g.ax_heatmap.legend(loc='center left',bbox_to_anchor=(1.01,0.85),handles=legend_TN,frameon=True)
l2.set_title(title='tissue type',prop={'size':10})
```

Comment: This allowed me to create a legend for the side bars. Any idea how to move the legend at the bottom (or right, or whatever)?
`clustermap` provides `cbar_kws` for doing that, but I keep getting errors if I use that argument