# Display legend of seaborn clustermap corresponding to the row colors

Tags: colors, seaborn, legend, heatmap

'''
For sake of simplicity, let's use the iris dataset. I would like to add a legend matching each species to its color code (blue,green, red in this example).
By the way, I found similar problems at the following links but were a bit more complicated.
[How to express classes on the axis of a heatmap in Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988846/how-to-express-classes-on-the-axis-of-a-heatmap-in-seaborn)

The solution proposed at [Seaborn clustermap row color with legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201172/seaborn-clustermap-row-color-with-legend) would have worked but for df[['tissue type','label']] when definig legend_TN, I'm not sure how to define the label similarly, like iris['species','xxxx']
Thank you in advance for helping me out.
'''

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
species = iris.pop('species')


lut = dict(zip(species.unique(), "rbg"))
row_colors = species.map(lut)
g = sns.clustermap(iris, row_colors=row_colors)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the examples at the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html), one could create a custom legend as:

```py
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

handles = [Patch(facecolor=lut[name]) for name in lut]
plt.legend(handles, lut, title='Species',
           bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure, loc='upper right')
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you so much Johan. That's exactly what I was looking for.