# Add label legend bar on seaborn heatmap plot

Tags: colors, label, seaborn, legend, heatmap

I'd like to customize my `seaborn heatmap` plot, by adding an extra bar on the y-axis that would illustrate the label of my indices.

Here is a toy example to illustrate my need:

```py
test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"A": [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)],
                               "B": [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)],
                               })

sns.heatmap(test)
```

[heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y55oN.png)

Let's say I have labels for each one of the Pandas indices like:

```py
labels = ["class1", "class1", "class1",  "class1", "class1", "class2", "class2", "class3", "class3", "class3"]
```

I'd like to add to the heatmap a bar on the y-axis with one color per label.

Thank you very much for your help !

PS: I saw this cool answer for `seaborn.clustermap` [How to express classes on the axis of a heatmap in Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988846/how-to-express-classes-on-the-axis-of-a-heatmap-in-seaborn)

But I don't think I directly applies to `seaborn.heatmap`

Comment: Maybe it would help if you'd add a mockup of the desired plot. Does it include a legend? Are there explicit labels for each of the y ticks?  You linked to a post with a clustermap without clusters, so basically it is just a heatmap. Why isn't it applicable to your situation?

Answer (score 0):

You are right @JohanC I apologize.

I thought I could not use `clustermap` because I did not want to do any clustering but just show labels on the side of the heatmap.

```py
test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"A": [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)],
                               "B": [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)],
                               })
                               
row_colors = pd.Series(["r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "b", "b", "g", "g", "g"])
labels_to_color = {0: "r", 1: "b", 2: "g"}

g = sns.clustermap(data=test, row_cluster=False, col_cluster=False, row_colors=row_colors)

for label in labels_to_color.keys():
    g.ax_col_dendrogram.bar(0, 0, color=labels_to_color[label],
                            label=label, linewidth=0)
g.ax_col_dendrogram.legend(loc="center", ncol=6)
```

It shows the labels as a barplot on the left side as expected.

[clustermap_with_labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc2gv.png)